# Evaluation of len(string) that should be False is evaluated as True

Tags: vb6

I read a file and split fields into variables and if I come into a variable which max length should be 32 I do this:

```
ragionesociale = Trim(Mid$(lineal, 159, 61))    
TRF_RASO = ragionesociale
If len(TRF_RASO < 32) Then
    TRF_RASO = TRF_RASO & Space(32 - Len(TRF_RASO))
Else
    TRF_RASO = Left$(TRF_RASO, 32)
End If
```

When it comes to evaluate the first condition len(TRF_RASO < 32) it evaluates as True, while if in the immediate window I put
    ? len(ragionesociale)

It gives me 38, so only the Else should be evaluated. Why does vb evaluate the first as true?
I hope to be clear when explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```
len(TRF_RASO < 32)
```

`(TRF_RASO < 32)` is a `False` expression which is 5 characters long when coerced to a string & passed to `Len()`, hence the incorrect result.

Correct to:

```
if len(TRF_RASO) < 32
```